# How do I select a named CSS element with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium in the Python environment together with the Chrome Webdriver to send the keys "123" into an input field named 'element_of_interest'. So far, only the full XPath seems to work, which is highly undesirable to me. Preferably, I want to select the element based on its name 'element_of_interest'. Selection based on IDs is not possible since IDs are generated dynamically.

Based on the inspector, the outerHTML chunk of interest is:

```
<div class="dhxform_control" akid="sStammCreateForm-element_of_interest" akstyle="input">
    <input class="dhxform_textarea" name="element_of_interest" id="dhxId_NFJ96uCXkPzp" type="TEXT" maxlength="16" autocomplete="off" style=""> 
   <div class="dhxform_note"></div>
</div>
```

Selection with

```
web.find_element(by = By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = "input[name='element_of_interest']").send_keys("123")
```

seems to not select nor input the keys into the desired field. However, I am not getting an error message. Similarily, By.NAME or By.XPATH using `"//*[@name='element_of_interest']"` doesn't do the trick neither. The only working solution (with the undesired Full Xpath) is:

```
web.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = "/html/body/div[18]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/input").send_keys("123")
```

I'd appreciate fresh thoughts on this issue. My goal is to select the element_of_interest based on its name. I am open to using By.CSS_SELECTOR, By.XPATH, By.NAME etc.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you've "cleansed" the code, but I don't see an input item named "stamm_nr_stamm_nr".  I see "element_of_interest".

Comment: When you say it "seems to not work at all"... what does that mean? Are you getting an error message? If so, edit your question and add any error message you are receiving.

Comment: Have you tried running your locator in the browser dev tools?  Run `$$()` for CSS selector and `$x()` for XPath. So run `$$("input[name='element_of_interest']")` and see if more than one element is found. If so, that's likely the problem.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I've adjusted the text slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a second same-named element behind the active popup layer. My element_of_interest was second in the HTML structure. Hence, the code

```
web.find_element(by = By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = "input[name='element_of_interest']").send_keys("123")
```

filled a non-active field behind the popup layer. The goal was thus to first retrieve a list of all same-named elements and then to choose the appropriate one. In my case, it was the second element in the list (retrievable by using `[1]`). This can be achieved with the following two approaches. Pay attention to the s in `find_elements`.

```
web.find_elements(by = By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = "input[name='element_of_interest']")[1].send_keys("123")
```

or

```
 web.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[name='element_of_interest']")[1].send_keys("123")
```